# How to link to Haskell static runtime with cabal and stack without hard coding ghc version?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I have a project which exports a shared static library and I use the following part in my `project.cabal` file

```
executable libsxp.so
    main-is:       Somefile.hs
    default-language: Haskell2010
    ghc-options: -shared -dynamic -fPIC -lHSrts-ghc7.10.2
```

The version of GHC is controlled using Stack, so is there a way wherein I can either get and append the version to make `-lHSrts-ghc{version}` or is there some config for it? I tried setting

```
stack build --ghc-options='-O0 -lHSrts-ghc7.10.2'
```

but it doesn't seem to pick it.

Also to clarify, `cabal install` is called by Stack and not by me.

Answer (score 3):

Does that cabal file work?  If so, then it should be sufficient to do something like this:

```
executable libsxp.so
    ghc-options: -shared -dynamic -fPIC
    if impl (ghc >= 7.10.2 && < 7.10.3)
        ghc-options: -lHSrts-ghc7.10.2
    else if impl (ghc >= 7.10.3 && < 7.10.4)
        ghc-options: -lHSrts-ghc7.10.3
    else if ...
```

BTW, why does your executable end in .so?  I've never seen that in an executable clause.

Are you sure you're using 7.10.2 and not 7.10.3?  Try `stack exec -- ghc --version`

Comment: Ya its 7.10.2 because of the resolver. We are exporting a bunch of haskell functions as an FFI in a shared lib , so its a shared lib - hence the so.
Wouldn't this imply that I'll have to write a separate condition for each version ? Any chance I can substitute a variable in cabal flags ? Also thanks for the reply

Comment: Yes , it works and the lib also works well as an FFI. Its just that it is hard coded to 7.10.2 now , which means that it'll invariably fail the next time we change the resolver

Comment: I don't think you can substitute a variable in cabal flags.  If you do find a good way to do that bit, you can get the GHC version by doing "stack exec -- ghc-pkg field ghc version --simple-output".  So something like roughly `stack build --ghc-options -lHSrts-ghc$(stack exec -- ghc-pkg field ghc version --simple-output)` could do it

Answer (score 1):

The general principle is described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6034881/1663197

> Using the configure style in Cabal, you can write a little configure
>   script that substitutes a variable for the output of the sdl-config
>   command. The values will then be replaced in a $foo.buildinfo.in file,
>   yielding a $foo.buildinfo file, that Cabal will include in the build
>   process.

---

First you need to switch your cabal `build-type` to `Configure` in project.cabal. Configure style is described in [cabal users guide](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#system-dependent-parameters). For build type `Configure` the contents of Setup.hs must be:

```
import Distribution.Simple
main = defaultMainWithHooks autoconfUserHooks
```

In case of handling GHC runtime version you can have a variable `@GHC_VERSION@` corresponding to it in a ***project*.buildinfo.in** file:

```
ghc-options: -lHSrts-ghc@GHC_VERSION@
```

Finally you write a **configure** bash script that gets GHC version as mgsloan suggested and generates ***project*.buildinfo** file by substitution of `@GHC_VERSION@` varibale in ***project*.buildinfo.in** file:

```
GHC_VERSION=$(stack exec -- ghc-pkg field ghc version --simple-output)
sed 's,@GHC_VERSION@,'"$GHC_VERSION"',' project.buildinfo.in > project.buildinfo
```

This way when build is started it will first execute **configure** script, then read **project.buildinfo** file and merge with **project.cabal**.

---

Also it may be worth to populate `extra-source-files` with configure and 
project.buildinfo.in; `extra-tmp-files` with project.buildinfo in **project.cabal**.

A more sophisticated solution may be inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2940799/1663197